# Ошибка дешифровки AES в Android: pad block corrupted

Tags: java, android, aes

Приветствую. В обучающих целях написал на Java программу для хранения паролей, использующую шифрование AES. Написал класс, в котором применяются методы из пакета javax.crypto. В приложении на Windows все отлично работает, шифрует и дешифрует. Решил сделать мобильную версию этого приложения на Android, для aes использовал тот же класс, но возникла проблема - данные не дешифруются, выкидывает исключение, сообщающее об ошибке дешифровки. Почему так происходит?

Исключение:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

Код моего класса:

```
public class AES {
    public static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(String data) {
        try {
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(data.getBytes());
            KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kg.init(128, sr);
                return (new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка при получении секретного ключа!");
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static byte[] Encode(SecretKeySpec sks, byte[] data) {
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
            return c.doFinal(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Ошибка операции шифрования!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] Decode(SecretKeySpec sks, byte[] data) {
        try {
            Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,sks);
            return c.doFinal(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка операции дешифровки");
        }
            return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Где же все эксперты?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел такой вариант:

```
byte[] result;
        SecretKeySpec sks=new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,"AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
        result=c.doFinal(data);
        return result;
```

Здесь используется вектор инициализации. Все прекрасно работает на андройде и на ПК, к тому же, говорят, что этот алгоритм более взломостойкий.

Answer (score 1):

[Статья на эту тему.](http://blog.kchandrahasa.com/blog/2013/08/09/android-4-dot-2-and-javax-dot-crypto-dot-badpaddingexception-pad-block-corrupted/) А также ответы на SO: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134336/1911548), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965699/1911548) и ещё множество других. Если кратко, то ваш метод `getSecretKeySpec` под Android будет при каждом вызове возвращать новый ключ. Быстрое, но **не рекомендованное** решение - заменить `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")` на `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto")`. Более правильный вариант - поменять тело метода на что-нибудь вроде:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
sr.nextBytes(salt);
KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(data.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
return key;
```